# Java JAR runs fine through command line, but not by double-clicking JAR

Tags: java, jar, jvm

Title is pretty self-explanatory I think. When I run the JAR, the following exceptions occurs:

[image: Error message]

So naturally I run it through the command prompt so hopefully the exception message and stack trace shows up but when I do that, it runs perfectly fine - everything works, no messages on the prompt (except for deliberate prints of course).

It's written in JDK 1.7.0_71 (64bit). I have JRE for that version, both 32 and 64-bit on my machine. I've force it with right-click->open with to use the javaw.exe from all three of them but each throws the same error. Putting `java -version` gets me:

```
java version "1.7.0_71"
Java (TM) SE Runtime Environment (build.1.7.0_71-b14)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.71-b01, mixed mode)
```

Windows 7 64-bit. NetBeans 8 (runs fine through NetBeans, no errors on output window). Program uses the GDAL, GeoTools, NetCDF, EJML, and JodaTime libraries.

I mean I'd provide more information but I'm not even sure where to start. Even just looking for advice on where to start just to learn what the problem is.

**UPDATE:** After just putting a message dialog in random lines until I could narrow down the issue, looks like the error is with the GDAL/OGR libraries. (The exact line is at `org.gdal.ogr.RegisterAll()`) The strange thing is why it works fine the other ways. At this point though I figure it's a GDAL specific question now as the GDAL bindings has been very weird and troublesome before.

Comment: Have you created an executable jar or a normal jar?

Comment: Just a normal .jar file

Comment: In the Java settings (in the Windows Control Panel if memory serves), you should be set it to show the Java console whenever a Java program runs. These will give you the errors you'd see from the commandline when running from the GUI.

Comment: Hm I set that option to show console but it doesn't show. I suppose I need a log off/on first?

Comment: Still console doesn't show. I guess for now I'll distribute it with a `.bat` file that just has `java -jar myprogram.jar` in it. That works although it sure seems very odd to be a necessary workaround..

Comment: You can check in regedit if your jarfile uses the same vm as your java -version. HKCR\jarfile\shell\open\command should shows as default the jvm location of your javaw.exe